# Lotus Quickr - QuickrlocaleUtil Error

Tags: lotus-domino

I have installed lotusquickr in my system. when i run an application called main.nsf in lotusquickr folder, i get the following error "QuickrLocaleUtil is Undefined". Since i am totally new to this, I have no idea what causes this error. Kindly help me.

Comment: I have forwarded your question onto colleagues who may be able to answer your question. They (or I) will advise soon.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Quickr version and how did you installed it, either one of the following documents will help you resolve the problem:

1. Domino console ClassCastException: Quickr Welcome page will not display (URL: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21444048)
2. Blank page or JavaScript error "Object expected" after install or upgrade of Lotus Quickr if you do not enable Domino Servlet Manager (URL: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21389017)